# VueJS: Getting values from multiple checkbox binding in textboxes

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

So I saw a simple example of multiple checkboxes from Vue's Docs [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Checkbox). The value for each selected checkbox is added to a bound array which is fine.

However for the app I am building I need a similar functionality but I want to be able to show values of checked checkboxes in corresponding textboxes.

[Here is an example of that.](http://jsbin.com/virifebigo/edit?html,js,output)

What I am looking for is the *value of each selected checkbox should be shown in corresponding textbox just below it*.

**N.B:**  I have a really big form and the form is generated dynamically which means I cannot create multiple bindings/data vars. I am looking for a way that just works based on the main `checkedNames` binding.

I thought of adding `v-model="checkedNames"` but it adds the same value in all textboxes not the one above it.

This should be simple but I am new to Vue so I can not figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, I have made some changes in your code

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="Jack" v-model="checkedNames">
<label for="jack">Jack</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="john" value="John" v-model="checkedNames2">
<label for="john">John</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="checkedNames3">
<label for="mike">Mike</label>
<br>

<input type="text" v-model="checkedNames">
<input type="text" v-model="checkedNames2">
<input type="text" v-model="checkedNames3">
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    checkedNames: [],
    checkedNames2: [],
    checkedNames3: []
  }
});
```

**For dynamic inputs**
You can use something like this:

HTML:

```
<div v-for="n in numberOfInputs">
  <input type="checkbox" name="jack{{n}}" id="jack{{n}}" value="Jack{{n}}" v-model="checkedNames[n]" >
  <label for="jack{{n}}">Jack{{n}}</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="checkedNames[n]">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var testComponent = new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    checkedNames: [],
    numberOfInputs: 5  
  },
  methods: {
    pageLoaded: function () {
      for(i=0;i<this.numberOfInputs;i++)
      {
           this.checkedNames.push([]);
      }
    }
  }

});

testComponent.pageLoaded()
```

Instead of `v-for="n in 5"` you can loop an array of form input data.
You can create an array of form list and give a unique id(instead of `n`) of each item and loop it, to generate form items.

Comment: Sorry about this but I have really big form and form is generated dynamically which means I cannot create multiple bindings. I am looking for a way that just works based on main `checkedNames` binding. Thanks

Comment: Ok :) Let me try for that

Comment: Hey! I have updated my answer. Can you check that? Is that you require? :)

Comment: Yes but there is one problem in your update, when I check last checkbox, it adds that value to first textbox instead of corresponding/nearby textbox. +1 for your effort so far :)

Comment: Yes I found that. Sorry. I am checking that issue :)

Comment: Hey! Finally got a way for that issue. I have updated my answer Can you check this code :)

Comment: Can you please how html should be for this updated code ?

Comment: I have updated the html code also under the heading "For dynamic inputs"

Comment: yes after adding `numberOfInputs` to `data`, thanks once again ! :)

Comment: Ok :) There may be even better ways to do this :)